# Does Google issue penalties for software or other programs private secure proxies for monthly rank cecking/backlink updating?

Tags: seo, rank-checkers, seo-software, seo-competition-analysis

Most SEOS have likely thought of this issue. I've been looking for a replacement for quite some time, with no luck when it comes to accuracy. Nothing is worse than when you show they client they are #2, but when they look, they are #9. Are secure proxies Recommended? Or can this hurt the SEO AND the client? Care more about the status of my clients' sites.

Comment: Results vary depending on if your logged into Google, your location, your device and previous searches. Use incognito and use the same postcode as your client in search options.

Comment: Automated queries are against their terms of service and prohibited by their webmaster guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en

Comment: Stephen, that is correct. But as of May 15th of this year, google starting showing ads on desktop computers who originally first saw the ad on their phone/tablet or other mobile device. You may be correct, perhaps it's a simple as being logged in, but I'm concerned that they are collecting unique identifyers UDID, amount other many ways to identify an individual.